# Hover on Highcharts Heatmap cell working only when hovering over data value, not the cell itself

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jasper-reports

i'm working on highcharts heatmap, onhover the cell should get highlighted with white background. It is working only when i'm hovering on the value, when i'm hovering on cell or its borders it is not working. 
I've used the following property for hover:

```
plotOptions.series.states.hover.color : "#FFFFFF"
```

Refer the images.

[image: Working on Hovering on cell value]
[image: Not working when not hovered on cell]

The default functionality should be when i hover on cell it should highlight background as white. I'm implementing it using jasper studio.

TIA

Comment: Maybe jasper studio uses old version of Highcharts? Or has something wrong inside. Highcharts lib works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6d35so3f/

Comment: @PawełFus I guess you are correct, when i'm trying it in fiddle it is working perfectly, if i'm using those properties in jasper then it is giving issues. If you find any workaround please let me know. Once check this fiddle at (x:0, y:0) hoverover is not working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4aqhB/263/)

Comment: For me point `{x: 0, y:0}` works perfectly fine. However I don't see data for point `{x: 4, y:1}`. For a workaround, sorry, I'm not familiar with jasper studio.